# Jenkins.log location on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop

Tags: logging, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

## Setup

I am currently running a Jenkins instance on an Ubuntu 14.04 desktop machine. I have installed Jenkins via WAR distribution and am running Jenkins as a service on the host machine.

## Issue

I am trying to access the jenkins.log file described [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging#Logging-LogsinJenkins) in the logging documentation on the Jenkins wiki. The purpose of accessing this file is to be sure we have a log to use in the event that Jenkins web UI is unavailable and there is an issue with Jenkins.

I've taken a look in /var/log/jenkins/ as the documentation suggests, however the only file in that folder is a config file.

Also, per the documentation, I have double checked the /etc/default/jenkins as well as the /etc/sysconfig/jenkins directories. Each one of these two directories does not exist on my machine.

I have also tried searching from command line using the 'find' command, as well as searching my system using the Ubuntu file explorer. Each of these approaches yielded no jenkins.log file.

## Questions

- Am I correct in my understanding that Jenkins system logs are output
  to the jenkins.log file?
- Where might the jenkins.log file be located on my machine?
- Is this the best approach in troubleshooting issues with Jenkins when the web UI is inaccessible?

Answer (score 6):

- Am I correct in my understanding that Jenkins system logs are output to the jenkins.log file?

  - *Yes you are rigth. Internal engines, plugins, etc saves its logs in jenkins log file*
- Where might the jenkins.log file be located on my machine?

  - *What is your command line which is executed as service in your machine?*
- Is this the best approach in troubleshooting issues with Jenkins when the web UI is inaccessible?

  - *Yes you have the jenkins log file or a web alternative : https://your.jenkins.com/log/all but jenkins.log has more information*

**Steps to find your jenkins log path**

- locate jenkins service file :

  **/etc/default/jenkins:** location for most of the Linux distributions.

  **/etc/sysconfig/jenkins:** location for RedHat/CentOS distribution.
- Open it and probably you will see :

  **NAME**=jenkins

  **JENKINS_LOG**=/var/log/$NAME/$NAME.log

  So your file /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log must be exist. If not like you said, try to add this line

Comment: I'm running Jenkins from `jenkins/jenkins:latest` and there are none of those files there.

Comment: Hi. Could you list your process with ? `ps -ef` With that you will see the real path of jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins does not write to any file, so there is no `jenkins.log` by default, instead it writes to the standard output.

So here is something we used in the `init.d` file:

```
JENKINS_WAR=/path/to/jenkins/war/jenkins.war
JENKINS_LOG=/path/to/jenkins/log/jenkins.log
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home

STARTUP="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xms4096m -Xmx8192m -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= -jar $JENKINS_WAR > $JENKINS_LOG 2>&1 &"
```

Also as suggested in the [doc](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging#Logging-MakinglogsavailableoutsideofthewebUI), you can use hook script to make it rotated.

You might also be interested in [Audit Trail Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Audit+Trail+Plugin).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Just so I and any programmer who has question understands, what exactly does the code you've provided do? Should the $JAVA_HOME variable as well as the $JENKINS_WAR variable be set to the current file paths for a user's Jenkins instance?

Also, what does -Xms4096m -Xmx8192m -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= -jar $JENKINS_WAR > $JENKINS_LOG 2>&1 & specify?

Comment: @J0991 Those are just `bash` tokens, in terms of `-Xms and -Xmx`, those are JVM parameters that we used. `-hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP` this is security property.
You can just use a plain one like this `java -jar $JENKINS_WAR > $JENKINS_LOG 2>&1 &`

Comment: The reason why we put like that is we have diff versions of Java installed. `/path/to/java/home` which is latest, `/path/to/java16/home` which is `java 1.6`