# Jenkins Simple Installation using 3GB Ram

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins 2.150 running under Docker without any job or extra configuration, just plain installation.

For me 3GB of ram to a plain installation is too much. Any tips to solve this problem?

Important: I'm using image Jenkins/Jenkins from docker hub

Comment: Do you have errors at Jenkins startup? Or Do you need tuning your Jenkins to run with 3GB or less?

Comment: I have no erros at startup, I need that Jenkins running less then 3GB

Comment: If you don't have any errors how do you know it's not working? I've run it on 2Gb without any problems, for a small number of jobs

Comment: As i said for me is very strange a Jenkins without any JOB use 3GB of RAM, this is too much. I have a friend running a jenkins under docker and using only 512MB of ram.

Comment: You said: "running under docker". Is your Jenkins running ? Do you need another docker configurations?

Comment: Yeah, my jenkins is running and working but using a lot of memory

Comment: Did #Donovan's answer help you?

Comment: Unhappy not, my error continue

Comment: Are your Jenkins running over Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Since Jenkins is a **JAVA** application, we could use the common **-Xmx -Xms -XX:MaxPermSize** parameters to configure the RAM usage of this java process.

Change the memory at docker level could throw **Out of Memory** exception beacause Jenkins has a pre-configured memory limits.

## Change Jenkins memory usage or limits

First you need to locate the Jenkins properties file. Commonly this is the path:

```
/etc/default/jenkins
```

If no body are manipulated your Jenkins you could find this:

```
# arguments to pass to java
#JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx256m"
```

Uncomment and change the **256** value to whatever you need.

```
# arguments to pass to java
JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx512m"
```

Finally restart your Jenkins according to your installation. In your case as you mention docker this would be enough

```
docker stop jenkins && docker start jenkins
```

---

After change java memory configurations, you could experience the classic exceptions like: **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**, you must need to configure an appropriate **-Xmx -Xms -XX:MaxPermSize** values

---

References:

- [Jenkins properties location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48475726/3957754)
- [Jenkins -Xmx -Xms -XX:MaxPermSize  configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14762164/3957754)

Answer (score 1):

Specify the max memory limits for the container when you run it: 
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory

```
docker run -m 512m jenkins/jenkins
```

512m = 512MB

Comment: If I do it I got OOM(Out of Memory) Killed - Exited with 137 code

Comment: What host are you running this on? Is the hosts' memory usage okay? Check your host memory usage and ensure there is memory available and that other containers aren't consuming it all.

Comment: My host is ok, I entered in Docker Jenkins and execute "top" command. I got Java process using about 3GB of ram

Comment: Oh, so it was still running when you tried the command I suggested? You might have to restart that container. What was your initial run command for the container? You're using some form or persistent storage for the jenkins_home directory, right?

Comment: If i use your command i got OOM Killed. I'm using a storage for jenkins_home

Comment: Did you stop the container first then run it?

Comment: So, without the memory limit, it's fine? That sucks. I'd say you'd have to tweak your memory limits (increase) or add the --memory-swap parameter in your run statement and set it to something higher like "1g" to use memory swapping. Have my sympathy.

Comment: --memory-swap parameter can be added to docker  ?